# User control not displayed after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a home.aspx page, where i have two panel. In first panel I have dynamically bound a User Control (for displaying meiny at left side) and in second I have displayed pages.
I bound user control dynamically at page load like.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/settings/Links/Navigation.ascx");
        Accordion1.Controls.Add(uc);          

    }
```

when page first time loaded my `usercontrol` is bind and my menus are displayed, but when I clicked on any menu item it hides(user control),

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this line of code on Page_Init event of Page life cycle.

```
UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/settings/Links/Navigation.ascx");
Accordion1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Proper way:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      //MyControl is the Custom User Control with a code behind file
      MyControl myControl = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");

      //UserControlHolder is a place holder on the aspx page where I want to load the
      //user control to.
      UserControlHolder.Controls.Add(myControl);

}
```

If you use `if (!IsPostBack)` then after postback it will not be added to the page. At the first time you will be able to see the control on the page.

Reference:
[ASP.NET Custom user control to add dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275625/asp-net-custom-user-control-to-add-dynamically)
[How to: Create Instances of ASP.NET User Controls Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It is okay. But when i click on any item (menu in my user control), it seems that it rebind, actually a flickering occur , how can i avoid this??

Comment: this flicker causes by the postback that happens every time you click the links , and this is a normal behaviour in asp.net,
note that the website you mentioned using the Ajax technology so thatpartial page updates can achieved ,and the page will be updated without submitting (posting ) the whole page . [ref](http://forums.asp.net/t/1160202.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

It's a dynamic control which must be recreated and readded to the page on every postback.

So this will work:

```
//if (!IsPostBack)
//{
    UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/settings/Links/Navigation.ascx");
    Accordion1.Controls.Add(uc);          
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamic control there is no need for `!IsPostBack` Property of page, Remove this property and use

```
UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/settings/Links/Navigation.ascx");
Accordion1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be loaded on each postback. keep the user control loading code outside if(!IsPostBack){}.